# javascript -- Uncaught ReferenceError: updateProductPrice is not defined -- function is there, but get the error

Tags: javascript, reference

I have a javascript that updates a product page pricing.  When the product is already created, the javascript works fine (it reads the ID value) and updates the various prices.

When I create a new product though I get a Uncaught ReferenceError: updateProductPrice is not defined.  I know the function is there, (using a call like OnKeyUp="updateProductPrice()"  ).

It is also declared before it is called. The really only difference is on a new product the GET info that is appended to the url is slightly different then on editing the product.

Any thoughts on why it would throw an error?

```
    <script language="javascript"><!--

function doRound(x, places) {
  return Math.round(x * Math.pow(10, places)) / Math.pow(10, places);
}


function updateNet() {
  var netValue = (document.getElementById('wholesalePrice').value * document.getElementById('pm0').value);
  document.getElementById('productsPrice' ).value = doRound(netValue, 4);
}


function updateProductPrice() {
  var wholesaleValue = document.getElementById('wholesalePrice').value;
  var netValue = (wholesaleValue * product_pricing[0]);
  document.getElementById('productsPrice').value = doRound(netValue, 4);
  for (var i = 0; i < product_pricing.length; i++) {
    var totalNum = (wholesaleValue * product_pricing[i]);
    document.getElementById('pp'+ i ).value = doRound(totalNum, 4);
  }
}


function updatePriceMultipier() {
  var wholesaleValue = document.getElementById('wholesalePrice').value;
  for (var i = 0; i < product_pricing.length; i++) {
    var MultiplierValue = document.getElementById('pm'+ i ).value;
    var totalPrice = (wholesaleValue * MultiplierValue);
    document.getElementById('pp'+ i ).value = doRound(totalPrice, 4);
  }
}

//--></script>
```

Comment: Why is there `<!--` at the start of script tag?

Comment: Tried with and without, some legacy code is all, did not make a difference if it was removed.

Comment: It's not possible to suggest anything because what you have posted looks all fine. Can you post a minimal demo reproducing your issue?

Comment: Yes the code works fine when I edit the product, the pricing updates exactly as expected.  Now when I load to create a new product (the GET info is the only page change) it fails and I get the reference error.  I look at the source code and it is there, I am at a loss as to why this is happening, other then maybe it needs to be set to a default other then zero?

Comment: Thanks, found the issue.